# Re-order Category Meta-data

Tags: posts, categories, post-meta

I am currently trying to re-order the categories displayed in a posts metadata.

The general functionality is that the order of category display is alphabetical (eg: categories - **G**lobal, **Y**our Voice).

Im trying to get the order of the categories on posts to instead be ordered by the post count (number of posts under each category).

I tried adding the general orderby query and set the value to count, but with no luck, any ideas?

This is the output code for the category metadata -

```
<?php lsx_post_meta_category(); ?>
```

Kind regards,
Joseph Hart

Comment: `lsx_post_meta_category()` is not a standard WordPress function. Please share the whole content of that function with us, otherwise we can't help you debug it.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. This is a custom theme function from the LSX theme - https://wordpress.org/themes/lsx/

It seems to be a custom function similar to <?php the_category(', ') ?> 

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section

My general understanding would be to include the function with the orderby parameter as so, but this has not worked: 

lsx_post_meta_category('orderby=count');

Comment: Please view the whole function located within the post-content.php template:



   `<?php } ?>

    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
   </h1>
  </header><!-- .entry-header -->
 <?php //} ?>
<div class="entry-meta">
  <?php lsx_post_meta_date(); ?> 
  <?php lsx_post_meta_author(); ?> 
  <?php lsx_post_meta_category(); ?>
</div><!-- .footer-meta -->`

Comment: Managed to configure a solution. The custom function <?php lsx_post_meta_category(); ?> was outputting the meta category data according to a specific layout function in the functions.php. The function starts as follows: `function lsx_post_meta_category() { $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());` I updated: `$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID());` To: `$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID(), array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'ASC') );` This array adds the required sorting to the category meta-data